# Xcode 4.6 - Problems posting text assigned to a UILabel to Facebook

Tags: facebook, label, uilabel

In Xcode 4.6, I have on a .xib page, a column of Labels each consisting of text, and to the right of which, are a set of play buttons to play each audio, such as in the .m code:

```
-(IBAction)pushButton {
    NSString *mytextfield = mylabelname.text; 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mysound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if(theAudio)[theAudio release];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    theAudio.volume = 1.0;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

When the sound is played, I assign the associated text of the label "mylabelname" to field mytextfield.  The .h file has the IBOutlet UILabel *mylabelname; declaration in the UIViewController, the .m has the -(void)mylabelname and the Outlet UILabel is connected to the label in the xib.

In the .m file, I do the Facebook post code like so:

```
-(IBAction)ShareFB1 {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        slComposeViewController = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
        slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [slComposeViewController setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posting to Facebook: %@", mytextfield]];    
        [slComposeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]];
        [self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Facebook Account" message:@"There are no Facebook accounts confiured, configure or create accounts in Settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

In the .m file, I get a warning on the NSString: Unused variable mylabelname.  I also get an error on the `slComposeViewController setInitialText` method: Use of undeclared identifier 'mylabelname'.

The only way I have gotten this to work, is to add the `NSString *mytextfield = mylabelname.text;` to the `-(IBAction)ShareFB1`, and the label value can be posted to Facebook, but since I have other labels on the page, I want the NSString value assigned outside of the `slComposeViewController setInitialText`.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: Rob: I am seeing your all questions, all are linked and having a small error. My advice is to just take a week time to read a full tutorials and then start development. You will save and feel good when you do this way. Instead of **worrying** on simple errors and warning, you need to invest 30minutes in stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Anoop, I have actually been developing in Xcode for over a year, and have multiple apps on the App Store, but this is just a part of coding in Objective C that I have not yet had to do.  This is probably a simple task, but I have not yet come across the tutorial that shows me how to do this.  I will keep looking.  Thanks, Rob

Comment: Rob, not an big issue for you. Anyways what the problem in this question?

Comment: The problem is that for posting the string of text to work, I have to declare the NSString *mytextfield = mylabelname.text; inside the -(IBAction)ShareFB1.  I want to set the NSString outside of the -(IBAction)ShareFB1, such as when another button is pressed on the same page.  This way, the string of text that is posted to Facebook can be dynamic, based on certain user actions (such as hitting a play button) next to the associated label.  If I set the NSString outside the -(IBAction)ShareFB1, I receive the Use of undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a property in .h file

```
@property(strong)NSMutableString *stringToPost;//if you wish to append, if replace then use NSString
```

In your .m file, in viewDidLoad method

```
self.stringToPost=[NSMutableString new];
```

And in all the IBActions method you can append the text(if you wish) or replace the previosly saved string:

```
//for appending
[self.stringToPost appendFormat:@"%@",yourTextField.text];

//for replacing with new one
self.stringToPost=yourTextField.text;
```

Comment: This was really helpful! I'm 99% of the way there. Your suggestion worked & the string can be posted to Facebook. I did see that in the .m, for the IBAction where I do the replace with new one: stringToPost=yourTextField.text; I had an error: Use of undeclared identifier 'stringToPost; did you mean '_stringToPost'?  I did the fixit and use _stringToPost, & also used _stringToPost in the setInitialText, then it worked, but even with working solution I get a warning: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableString *' from NSString * - I'll have to look up how to fix incompatible types

Comment: Maybe I need to alloc and init the NSMutableString

Comment: Yes I edited my answer. And if you assing NSString to NSMutableString then this is the warning. If you dont have to append then simply convert to NSString in .h and .m

Comment: I tried adding [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:mylabelname.text];  and also used the self.stringToPost=yourTextField.text; but I still get the incompatible pointer types.  I am going to have to get some sleep for now, and I will bang away at this more tomorrow  I think you got me most of the way there at this point, I will post more tomorrow - Thanks Anoop!

Comment: I couldn't stop, and got this working.  Solution:
.h file has:
@property(strong)NSString *stringToPost;   .m file has in ViewDidLoad method: self.stringToPost=[NSString new];   IBActions use: self.stringToPost=yourTextField.text;  And lastly, in the actual posting to Facebook, I do: [slComposeViewController setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posting to Facebook: %@", self.stringToPost]]; Seems to work well, no warnings or errors.  I think this should do the trick!  Thanks Anoop!

Comment: Just a quick update - Anoop is awesome, he really got me through this one.  Thanks to his guidance, I feel like I have cracked this thing wide open, and I am rocking the code across all my pages in my app.  Thanks Anoop!